# Is there a reason the electrician didn't ground this generator voltage selector switch?

Tags: grounding, generator

I have a cabin where the only source of power is a generator. The plugs that I can plug into it look like this:

[image]

One plug is 120 and one plug is 240. The larger box above allows me to switch between the two.

From here there is 8/3 running into the house (red, black, white, ground).

[image]

Behind the large panel in the first pic is a ground wire just coiled up. It doesn't go to anything.

[image]

Is there a reason the electrician would have left the ground like this? Shouldn't this go into a grounding rod?

Comment: maybe they grounded their non-floated generator, which is what you'd need to do to use it like that.

Comment: This is why electricians and inspectors are different people.  Stuff happens.  Maybe he was planning on connecting it but something came up.

Comment: Not sure why you deleted all the pictures and details. Without them there's no hope of getting an answer...